# How does BigQuery processes data?

Tags: google-bigquery

My question is about how BigQuery is processing data. 
When I run this simple query on a sessions table

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId
from
  `Project_1.Dataset_1.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
  1=1
  AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r'(\d+)') >= '20190324'
```

I get the message

```
Query complete (0.7 sec elapsed, 35.7 KB processed)
```

However, when I store the string '20190324' in a table named 'temp' and re-run the query by replacing '20190324' with a query result

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId
from
  `Project_1.Dataset_1.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
  1=1
  AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r'(\d+)') >= (select dd from temp)
```

then the amount of time and data processing volume increases dramatically:

```
Query complete (20.5 sec elapsed, 784.3 MB processed)
```

Someone would expect these two queries to require the same processing time & data. I was wondering if anyone has any insight on why this is happening.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55307282/wildcard-table-matches-with-table-suffix-and-sub-query) has some good examples when scanned size can be reduced.

Comment: Filters on _TABLE_SUFFIX that include subqueries do not limit the number of tables scanned for a wildcard table. See more [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix)